# Trying to get Class with parameter that is generic

Tags: java, class, generics

I am trying to instatiate a class from a String using:

```
Class configClass = Class.forName(configClassName);
Class testClass = Class.forName(className);
Constructor constr = testClass.getConstructor(configClass);
TestCase testCase = (TestCase) constr.newInstance(configClass);
```

The constructor in the class RecursiveLinkTest that extends TestCase looks like this:

```
public RecursiveLinkTest(Class<JsonConfig> configClass)
```

As you can see the parameter in RecursiveLinkTest is of the typ Class. How can i get the constructor for the class? I am getting NoSuchMethodException when I run my code. (It can create the Class objects configClass and testClass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem:

```
Constructor constr = testClass.getConstructor(Class.class);
```

You need to get the constructor with the Class as the argument.

Comment: Yes. You have to use the class of Class here. Confusing :)

Comment: Thanks, almos but it helped me! I did configClass.getClass() and it worked.

Comment: @alexandernajafi Interesting, I thought because of erasure those instances are the same. I guess I was wrong. Thanks for the correction.